# EF Core - Do I have to have a "using" statement to have my context disposed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Suppose my class injects a DbContextFactory, then I can write a method like this...

```
private async Task<List<Device>> GetDevices() {
  await using AppDbContext ctx = await ContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
  return await ctx.Devices.ToListAsync();
}
```

If I understand correctly, then as I create the context with a `using`, then it will be disposed of when the method ends.

Suppose I rewrite my method as follows...

```
private async Task<List<Device>> GetDevices() =>
  await (await ContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync()).Devices.ToListAsync();
```

Will the context be correctly disposed in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to create and dispose context in your functions? Wouldnt it massively slow down your API?

Comment: Because I'm using Blazor, and if you do regular injection, it holds on to the one context for the lifetime of the component.  This isn't always what you want, for example, when using filtering in `Include`, you get back all entities in th econtext, even if they don't match the filter. [MS recommend using a context factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to create a context whenever you need it. Apparently it's fast enough not to be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, and cheers I like your picture

Comment: @Mohammed You mean the turkey! He's way more attractive than me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to dispose it. See this article for more information: https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/

Quoting from the article:

> The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no longer needed. E.g. when you execute a query and iterate over query results using "foreach", the call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() will cause the connection to be opened, and when later there are no more results available, "foreach" will take care of calling Dispose on the enumerator, which will close the connection. In a similar way, a call to DbContext.SaveChanges() will open the connection before sending changes to the database and will close it before returning.
> Given this default behavior, in many real-world cases it is harmless to leave the context without disposing it and just rely on garbage collection.

Your rewritten function is fine!

Comment: Brilliant, just what I hoped! I find expression-bodied methods much neater. Thanks

Comment: This is INCORRECT as the OP is using `CreateDbContext` not injecting the actual `DbContext `.

Answer (score 1):

The original answer here is incorrect. You DO need to dispose of instances created with `CreateDbContext()` as the contexts created through the context factory DO NOT get disposed.

See the microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

> Notice that the DbContext instances created in this way are **not** managed by the application's service provider and therefore must be disposed by the application.